# How to execute a function of an Erlang module from a shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have a novice question. I'm reading the book "Erlang Programming" and working on exercises after every chapter.

In the situation that I have a `db.erl` module, and inside it I've placed several functions for several exercises. After a few days of playing with exercises I've grown tired from repeating "compile->execute exercise-function" actions in the `erl` shell. Let's say I'm working on `new()` function in the `db.erl` module; after each modification of this function, I'm forced to do next in `erl`:

```
c(db.erl).
db:new().
```

again and again. Sometimes I forget to re-load my module and the results are confusing. I can compile/load through OS shell using:
`erl -compile file.erl; erl -make`, but I did not find a way to run specific function from specific module. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-eval` option:

```
$ erl -eval 'io:format("printing ~p~n", [{any, term}]), init:stop()' -noshell
printing {any,term}
```

Read documentation here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html

And you can use just `erlc` to compile files: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlc.html

Comment: It works, thank you. Also, as I understand it is a very-very "tricky" way of doing things. Is there some erlang-way of testing simple applications (maybe using some tools or whatever)?